# Running npm by short path with quotes ("npm.cmd") causes it to searching for `npm-cli.js` by wrong path

Tags: windows, npm, path, environment-variables, quotes

I just call `npm -v`. Let's see 6 ways to call it:

1. [Ok] `npm -v`
2. [Ok] `npm.cmd -v`
3. [Ok] `"C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm" -v`
4. [Ok] `"C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd" -v`
5. [Error] `"npm" -v`
6. [Error] `"npm.cmd" -v`

The error is: `Cannot find module '<current directory value>\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'`
(code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND')

JFYI: `Path` env.variable contains only right value: `C:\Program Files\nodejs\`

So, why using the quoted short(relative to the env. variable `Path`) path of npm causes it to search for `npm-cli.js` by the wrong path - relative to the **current directory** instead of relative to the **npm.cmd(or npm executable) location**?